# Logo recognition using emguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, sift

I have implemented [this](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SURF_feature_detector_in_CSharp) code and have detcted logo in couple of images,
I was able to get some results like this [image: this] but I need to count that how many images contain this logo,
may be something like finding all keypoints of logo inside big image or some thing else.
I can see I have foud the logo inside big image but I want to confirm it programetically, using emguCV.
Please help.

## -- edited

this is the piece of code with homography, can you guide me a bit here, because I am totaly new to emguCV and openV please help me counting these inlier

```
public static Mat Draw(Mat modelImage, Mat observedImage, out long matchTime)
    {
        Mat homography;
        VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints;
        VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints;
        using (VectorOfVectorOfDMatch matches = new VectorOfVectorOfDMatch())
        {
            Mat mask;
            FindMatch(modelImage, observedImage, out matchTime, out modelKeyPoints, out observedKeyPoints, matches,
               out mask, out homography);

            //Draw the matched keypoints
            Mat result = new Mat();// new Size(400,400), modelImage.Depth, modelImage.NumberOfChannels);
            Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches(modelImage, modelKeyPoints, observedImage, observedKeyPoints,
               matches, result, new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), mask);

            #region draw the projected region on the image

            if (homography != null)
            {
                
                //draw a rectangle along the projected model
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, modelImage.Size);
                PointF[] pts = new PointF[]
                {
                      new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Bottom),
                      new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Bottom),
                      new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Top),
                      new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Top)
                };
                pts = CvInvoke.PerspectiveTransform(pts, homography);

                Point[] points = Array.ConvertAll<PointF, Point>(pts, Point.Round);
                using (VectorOfPoint vp = new VectorOfPoint(points))
                {
                    CvInvoke.Polylines(result, vp, true, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 5);
                }

            }

            #endregion

            return result;

        }
    }
```

Comment: compute a homography from the matches and count the inlier. If manny of the matches support a single homography it is more likely that they describe the desired logo.

Comment: @Micka please see edited protion of question what do i need to do this homography now.

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer is a bit to late, but may I can help someone other. With following code snipppet you can count the matching feature points that belongs to you question (counting lines). The importents variables is the *mask* variable. It contains the informations.

```
private int CountHowManyParisExist(Mat mask) { 

Matrix<Byte> matrix = new Matrix<Byte>(mask.Rows, mask.Cols);
mask.CopyTo(matrix);

var matched = matrix.ManagedArray;
var list = matched.OfType<byte>().ToList();
var count = list.Count(a => a.Equals(1));

return count; 
}
```